# How to append data using joblib?

Tags: python, joblib

I am trying to save data using `joblib.dump()` at different points in my workflow, and want to append data to my save file as I move along the workflow. When I try to do this, I end up with the original dictionary every time with nothing appended. I am using syntax similar to `json.dump()`.

Here is what I tried:

```
foo_path = base_directory + r'append_try.pkl' # note base_directory is a full absolute path
init_data = {'yummy': 1, 'funny': 2}
second_data = {'sunny': 3, 'runny': 4}
# dump initial data
with open(foo_path, 'wb') as io:
    joblib.dump(init_data, io)
```

Now just make sure that worked:

```
with open(foo_path, 'rb') as io:
    foo_dat = joblib.load(io)
print(foo_dat)  #this works
```

Now try appending `second_data`, and then load the file to see if it worked:

```
# Similar syntax to json.dump
with open(foo_path, 'ab') as io:
    joblib.dump(second_data, io)

# see if it worked
with open(foo_path, 'rb') as io:
    foo_dat2 = joblib.load(io)
print(foo_dat2)
```

And this just returns the initial data.Note I have also tried specifying the write mode as `a+b` and `ab+`. Those didn't work either. Also, while this is a simple example with numbers, in my application I am saving numpy arrays, so I can't just use `json.dump()`.

As a workaround, I'm currently appending the additional information to the dictionary in my code, and overwriting the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the joblib library specifically, but since you dumped into the file twice, this will create a file that contains two objects, not a list of two objects. So you'll probably need to load() twice as well from the same file object:

```
with open(foo_path, 'rb') as io:
    foo_dat1 = joblib.load(io)
    foo_dat2 = joblib.load(io)
```

Reading concatenated file may work if the `joblib.load()` method knows to only read exactly what it needs to read and leaves the file object at the start of the next object, like the `pickle.load()` that it's based on. It should be noted that `json.load()` doesn't support reading concatenated json either, it expects that the file contains only a single, complete JSON object, and would raises Extra data error if you try to read a file created by concatenating multiple objects together into a single file.